# Finding a stud in a highrise appartment

Tags: ceiling, studs, joists

I would like to install my xpole in my apartment but I am unable to find the stud in the ceiling.  According to my stud finder the entire ceiling is metal.  Can anyone help?  I am in a 24 story concrete highrise.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: There are no studs in ceilings. If you mean a joist, it may not be there because many multi-story modern buildings do not use ceiling joists.

Answer (score 1):

Your ceiling drywall is probably not directly attached to any structural members.  It is pretty common in newer multistory buildings to put sound damping resilient channel between the two.  And there is only enough structural support for the drywall/lights and not any additional loads.